# can't I use ifstream in a function that called for istream as a parameter?

Tags: c++, ifstream

This is the drill for Chapter 10 in *Programming Principles and Practice Using C++*. 
The program work with points:

1. it prompt the user to input (x,y) pairs. They are then stored in a vector of Points called `original_points`.
2. the original points are printed to a file
3. the program then read the file to retrieve the same points, stored in a vector of points called `processed_points`
4. the two vectors are compared, if they are not the same, the program throws an error.

The problem is that the `processed_points` has a `size()` of 0, that happens only when I use `get_vector_points()` to get those points. What is wrong with the function?

```
//put any vector points from ist into points
void get_vector_points(istream& ist, vector<Point>& points)
{
    //this function is bad, it doesn't do anything the second time you use it
    while(true)
    {
        Point p;
        if( ist >> p)
            points.push_back(p);
        else return;
    }
}
//
void write_to_file(string& path, vector<Point>& v_of_points)
{
    //open output file
    ofstream ofile(path);

    //output results to file
    for(Point p : v_of_points)
    {
        ofile << p <<endl;
    }

    //close output stream
    ofile.close();
}
void read_from_file(string& path, vector<Point>& v_of_points)
{
    //open input file
    ifstream ifile(path);

    //read from file : Here comes trouble
    get_vector_points(ifile, v_of_points);

    //But no problem if you do the following instead
    //    while(true)
    //    {
    //        Point p;
    //        if( ifile >> p)
    //            v_of_points.push_back(p);
    //        else break;
    //    }
}
//read point from specified istream ist, format:(0,0)
//output points from specified ostream ost, format:(0,0)
void points_drill(string path)
{
    //read from console a vector of points
    vector<Point> original_points;
    get_vector_points(cin, original_points);

    //write the same vector to file
    write_to_file(path,original_points);

    //read the same vector from file, but call it processed
    vector<Point> processed_points;
    read_from_file(path,original_points);

    //they should be the same
    for (int i= 0; i < original_points.size(); i++)
    {
        if (original_points.size()!=processed_points.size())
            throw runtime_error("Size Mismatch"); //error here and proccesed_point has size of 0
        if (original_points[i]!=processed_points[i])
            throw runtime_error("something is wrong!");
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using a custom Point. Full code is available at http://pastebin.com/ZvfcZxf3

Any comment on the coding style/readability is appreciated.

Comment: `get_vector_points` reads from `cin`, not from the stream passed to it, `ist`

Comment: Ok, I have corrected that and attempt to run it again. the same error persists. Hmmm...

Comment: I have just caught another mistake, I wrote     `read_from_file(path,original_points);` instead of     `read_from_file(path,processed_points);` I can't believe I missed it. That's the end of this problem.

Comment: ... that's exactly what I wrote in my answer five minutes ago

Comment: I guess that part of the page didn't refresh, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call

```
read_from_file(path,original_points);
```

is reading into the vector `original_points`, not `processed_points`

Answer (score 2):

You should try a different way to read in the file:

```
void get_vector_points(istream& ist, vector<Point>& points)
{
   std::string line;
   std::string first, second;
   while(std::getline(ist,line)) 
   // this should get every line in the file as a string.
   // if the formatting of the file is 2 doubles per line.
   // You will need to do the parsing yourself by grabbing each value
   {
   // example first line:    123   321
    first = line.split[0]; // this is not a real function this is just Psudo code
    //first = "123"
    second = line.split[1];// for parsing text and splitting into 2 doubles
    // second = "321"
    Point p;
    p.x = atoi(first); // atoi is = ascii to int.  Makes a string intager into a 
    p.y = atoi(second);// actual int data type
    // p.x = 123   p.y = 321
    points.push_back(p)
    else return;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, your function `get_vector_points` will put the input stream to a fail state. You might check EOF and read delimiters (white spaces) to avoid it.

Here with integers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

std::istream& get_integers(std::istream& stream, std::vector<int>& integers)
{
    int n;
    // Read integers and trailing white spaces.
    while( ! stream.eof() && stream >> n) {
        integers.push_back(n);
        stream >> std::ws;
    }
    return stream;
}

int main()
{
    std::istringstream input(" 1 2 3 ");
    std::vector<int> integers;
    // Read and test the result:
    if( ! get_integers(input, integers)) std::cout << "Failure\n";
    else {
        for(int i : integers)
            std::cout << i;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```